# how to set a hash data with multi fields and values one time?

Tags: c#, hash, redis, servicestack

how to set a hash data with multi fields and values one time ?

use by C#, ServiceStack.Redis

like native method : “HMSET”

help me and thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
redis_write.HMSet(string.Format("u:{0}:info", Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value),
                        new byte[][] { 
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Name") ,
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Sex") ,
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Birth") ,
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("iURL") ,
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Info") ,
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("RegLocal") 
                        },
                        new byte[][] { 
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["Name"].ToString()),
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["Sex"].ToString()),
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["Birth"].ToString()),
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["iURL"].ToString()),
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["Info"].ToString()),
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Request["country"].ToString()+","+Request["province"].ToString()+","+Request["city"].ToString())
                        });
```

but，there are too much garbled between key chars and value chars[image]